# How to take a sheet from one SpreadsheetDocument and add it to another in c#

Tags: c#, .net, excel, openxml

In my c# .net project I have a controller action that has two excel SpreadsheetDocuments, I would like to take the first sheet of the second workbook and add it to the first workbook (so the first workbook will have two sheets).

My code currently looks like this

```
SpreadsheetDocument doc1 = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(stream, true);
SpreadsheetDocument doc2 = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(stream2, true);
var breakSheet = doc2.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Sheets.FirstChild;
doc1.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Sheets.Append(breakSheet);
stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
return File(stream, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, String.Format(fileName));
```

However on line 3 of this code I get the error "Cannot insert the OpenXmlElement "newChild" because it is part of a tree."

I know both of the SpreadsheetDocuments are valid because when I just return either one individually without attempting to combine them they both export successfully with the right data. So how can I successfully combine these two sheets?

Comment: Sorry I meant to say line 4 "doc1.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Sheets.Append(breakSheet);"

Answer (score 1):

If you can, I would suggest you to use ClosedXML, and [copy the worksheet](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/wiki/Copying-Worksheets)

There it might look like that:

```
    private static void CopyWorksheet(Stream sourceStream, Stream targetStream)
    {
        var wb1 = new XLWorkbook(sourceStream);
        var wb2 = new XLWorkbook(targetStream);
        var sh1 = wb1.Worksheets.First();

        sh1.CopyTo(wb2, sh1.Name + " from wb1");

    }
```

Comment: I am not reading these files from disk, I am generating them with data from a database. Is there an easy way to convert the stream or SpreadsheetDocument into an XlWorkbook?

Comment: Yes, XLWorkbook can also be created from Stream.

Comment: Ive changed my code to look like that but when I open up the excel file the data is slightly corrupted. After the CopyTo I have  wb2.SaveAs(stream);, is that the correct method or are there other ways?

Comment: I did not work with streams yet, but what you did sounds right - to save to file. Maybe try to isolate the operation by saving the strema first, and then make the operation of transfering the worksheet separately (as in my first suggestion-code)